# Simple app to create advanced apps

Tags: automation

I need to build a free app that does straight **condition-action** *events*

It must allow advanced manipulation of phone functions, like turning on/off radios, monitor sensor state, launch other apps, read SMS content, reas notifications, lock phone, etc.

**[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** is the closest example,  but it's a complete mess. You can't, for instance, launch multiple tasks on a single profile without heavy workarounds

Any suggestion ?

**Update:**

Thank you for the support given this far.
I've tested:

**- [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/)** - Not free (the "free" is completely limited)

**- [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate)** - Beats tasker on the ease to use, but doesn't beat Tasker on the required functionalities. Hits the same wall as tasker, being unable to assign two or more actions to the same trigger

**- [MIT App Inventor](https://appinventor.mit.edu/)** - Seems very complete, but I couldn't go far: the developing interface (browser) is glitchy

I'm still open to the idea of building myself an app, if one could find an app maker that requires simple programming language

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried IFTTT?  You may need pro for multiple tasks on a single profile but it works great on Android!

Comment: Tried just now. Gonna have to thank you for the effort... Quite useless without pro, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately yes.  Another alternative is [automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&referrer=utm_source%3Dhomepage).  If this answer helped, I would much appreciate it if you marked it as the answer :).

Comment: I enjoyed this Automate. The building is intuitive and not complicated. It's also quite complete. But it falls on the same problem as tasker, not being able to link two actions to a single trigger. The "OK" hook from the blocks supports only one "In". Also, there's no option to read the content of an SMS. Since I have tasker here, I'd rather stick with it, for now.

Comment: Alright sounds good. Glad I could help!